# undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Link:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to follow some lessons on creating a list type of forum.

Now the problem is to the `Destroy` function:

> undefined method `model_name' for
>   ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Link:Class

For this line in show.html.erb (app/views/links/show.html.erb where line #25 raised:)

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @link, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

**Links controller**

```
Class LinksController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @link = Link.all        
        #@link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end    

    def new
        @link = Link.new
    end 

    #added from others 
    def edit 
        @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end    

    def destroy
        @link = Link.find(params[:id])
        if @link.destroy
            redirect_to @link, :notice => 'Link successfully deleted'
        else 
            render show: 'action'
        end 
    end     

    def create
        @link = Link.new(link_params)
        @link.user_id = current_user.id
        #@link.save
        if @link.save
            redirect_to @link, :notice => 'Link successfully created'
        else 
            render action: 'new'
        end 
    end 

    private

    def link_params
        params.require(:link).permit(:url, :title) #need to add :user_id?
    end    
end
```

Snippets from the show.html.erb

```
<%= @link.each do |link| %>
<%#link_to(link.title, link.url) %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to link.title, link.url %></td>
        <td><%#= link.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', link %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(@link) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @link, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

This is the routes.rb

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :pages
  root :to => "pages#index"
  resources :links
End
```

**Separately, theres another issue.**

The resulting links page also throws up the entire Link database in gibberish form as well as the table form I displayed.

Comment: Uncomment the `@link = Link.find(params[:id])` in the `show` method.This would resolve the main issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your show action you have

```
def show
  @link = Link.all  # this is commented out in your code     
  #@link = Link.find(params[:id])
end
```

Your **@link is nil because you have commented it out**, uncomment it and it will show up. Also if you want to *show all the links then you should use* `index action not show`. *Show action should be use for showing that particular link*

**Edit:**

According to your comment your index action should be like this:

```
def index
  @links = Link.all
end
```

and show action should be

```
def show
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
end
```

and your html code should be in **index.html.erb**

```
<%= @links.each do |link| %>
  <%#link_to(link.title, link.url) %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to link.title, link.url %></td>
    <td><%#= link.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', link %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(@link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', link, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>      </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Note the destroy link i have used. I have used **`link and not @link`** as you are inside a loop and you have access to your link by `link` and not `@link`

Comment: Hi Mandeep, thanks alot! 
I tried to have Def Index within the LinksController but gave back the same error. However, uncommenting solved it? Not sure if its messy structure but I followed the tutorial which didnt have the Def index.

Comment: Ok now theres no errors but the table of entries does not appear. (earlier before the error and my attempt to trouble shoot, it displayed the entries in gibberish and in the table form.

Comment: @user3395829 that should be a separate question and make sure you add your full view :)

Comment: Ok got it, and by full view meaning?

Comment: @user3395829 your view file where you have your table

Comment: Thanks!! Its just blank...i.e not showing. View file is in show.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56481/discussion-between-mandeep-and-user3395829).

Answer (score 1):

Change `@link` to `link` inside the loop

```
<%= @link.each do |link| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link.user_id %></td>

    ..
    <td>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', link, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    </td>
```

`link_to 'Destroy', link` is shortcut for  `link_to 'Destroy', link_path(link)`

`@link`, in this case is `Link.all`, but what you need is the local variable `link` which is the individual `Link` object